# Add incrementing numbers per line in UNIX

Tags: unix

Hi all I'm new in scripting in UNIX and  I'm trying to add incrementing numbers per line. For example i have sample.txt and inside sample.txt is

inside sample.txt:

```
Name1
Name2
Name3
..
..
.. 
Name26
```

and I want to make it look like this;

```
1Name1
2Name2
3Name3
..
..
.. 
26Name26
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: why not `26name26`?? If really `4name26`, then you'll have to describe the rules for incrementing the leading number. Do you know about `cat -n file` ? Is that good enough? Good luck.

Comment: sorry typo. i want it to be edited not just cat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said you do not want `cat`, but sample.txt edited.
It is a lot easier to find a solution with a temp file, something like `cat`, `awk` or (depending on the exact layout you want)

```
# grep with numbers every line, the dot for any character and * for possible 0 times
grep -n '.*' sample.txt ' > sample.txt.tmp && mv sample.txt.tmp sample.txt
# OR: 
# grep added a :, do want to delete it?
grep -n '.*' sample.txt | sed 's/://' > sample.txt.tmp && mv sample.txt.tmp sample.txt
```

When you make a script looping through the number of lines of the file (using `wc`) and call `sed -i` for each line you will have created a monster. `sed -i` will use a tmp file just as I did, but now for every line !